# how to delete row from coredata (Entity) ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview, core-data

i am new to CORE DATA in my app i am using coredata.
i just stored data in my core data. my entity name is "FEED" and i have a rows with name "title", "id " , "link" ,"desc" so now i want to delete perticular row on based on "id". so how can i do this?

Here is my code,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : MessageMusicCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageMusicCell") as! MessageMusicCell

    cell.pinButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.pinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MessageViewController.buttonDeletePressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.selectionStyle = .None



        person = people[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_title_msg_music.text = person!.valueForKey("title") as? String
        cell.img_message_music.image = UIImage(named: "PlaceHolder")
        cell.desc_msg_music.text = person!.valueForKey("desc") as? String


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print(people.count)
        return people.count


}

func buttonDeletePressed(sender:UIButton) {


}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell : MessageMusicCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageMusicCell") as! MessageMusicCell


}
```

so how can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Like this,

```
func buttonDeletePressed(sender:UIButton) {

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let index = sender.tag

        context.deleteObject(people[index] as NSManagedObject)
        people.removeAtIndex(index)

        let _ : NSError! = nil
        do {
            try context.save()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print("error : \(error)")
        }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `let _ : NSError! = nil` :')

Answer (score 1):

```
func deleteFeed(id:String)
{
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate?.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"FEED")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", "\(id)")
    do
    {
        let fetchedResults =  try managedContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]

        for entity in fetchedResults! {

            managedContext?.deleteObject(entity)
        }
    }
    catch _ {
        print("Could not delete")

    }
}
```

Now you can call this function and pass the id whatever you want to delete

```
func buttonDeletePressed(sender:UIButton){
   deleteFeed("1")
}
```

Comment: let index = sender.tag
        print(index)
        let feedId = person?.valueForKey("feed_id")?.objectAtIndex(index)
        deleteFeed(feedId! as! String)

Comment: by above code i get that Nfstring ObjectAtindex can not use

Comment: So how can i get my feed id there?

Comment: let btnPostion = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(btnPostion)

you can use this two line to get perticular index of table view cell

Comment: ok you mean to say you facing issue how to get seleted indexpath for tableview right ?

just put below 2 lines in your buttonDeletePressed function and you will get selected indexpath for row 

`let btnPostion = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(btnPostion)
print(indexpath.row)

now fetch your feed id from array using like a 

let feedID = arrayOffeed[indexpath.row]as! String
print(feedID)`

try this one

Comment: @AnkurKathiriya I am trying to do similar thing for my app which I am developing. I am getting an error though, when I am using `let managedContext = appDelegate?.managedObjectContext`  i am getting an error under `appDelegate?.managedObjectContext ` and says ** Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'**

Answer (score 0):

You can delete data like,

```
  let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        context.deleteObject(myData[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
        myData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        context.save(nil)
```

this is done from `commitEditingStyle` so here used `indexPath.row`. You can pass your id if you want to delete data from other place. If you want to delete data from tableview then you should implement `commitEditingStyle` and delete data like mentioned above.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
switch editingStyle {
    case .Delete:
    // remove the deleted item from the model
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    context.deleteObject(people[indexPath.row] )
    people.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch _ {
    }

    // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Hope this could be of some help!