# Deleting object in coreData ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am getting `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION Error` while deleting a record from core data. Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        //deleteIncidents()

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        context.delete(candles[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
        candles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        do{

            try context.save()
        }
        catch{

        }

        //tableView.reloadData()
        // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559445/how-to-delete-row-from-coredata-entity-ios-swift/37559834#37559834

Answer (score 0):

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
```

Have you use this code .Even getting crash .May be that is the problem with your predicate one of your predicate is getting null value are.you want to fetch the data from the core data with null value which is not available in data base.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using following method to delete

```
context.delete(candles[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
```

you should use

```
context.deleteObject(candles[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
```

> `- (void)delete:(id)sender` : Remove the selection from the user interface.
>   This method is invoked when the user taps the Delete command of the editing menu. A subclass of UIResponder typically implements this method by removing the selected object from the user interface and, if applicable, from the application’s data model. It should not write any data to the pasteboard. The command travels from the first responder up the responder chain until it is handled; it is ignored if no responder handles it. If a responder doesn’t handle the command in the current context, it should pass it to the next responder.
>
> `- (void)deleteObject:(NSManagedObject *)object` : Specifies an object that should be removed from its persistent store when changes are committed.
>   When changes are committed, object will be removed from the uniquing tables. If object has not yet been saved to a persistent store, it is simply removed from the receiver.